# set height in CSS to get to the bottom of the viewport from the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is this possible? I have the following layout:

```
<div class="toolbar">
</div>

<div class="dates-bar">
</div>

<div class="search-bar">
</div>

<div class="scroll-view">
    <table class="table-view">
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I need the scroll-view to go stretch to the bottom of the viewport, so it will scroll if the `number of rows * height of the row` overflow from the scroll-view.

That way I can keep all the blocks above the scroll-view "fixed". I can't use fixed position for those elements because they are inside another container and that container uses flexbox, so I don't have the width and the height.

My attempts have been `"height: 100%" and "height: 100vh"` but I need something like `"calc(100% - height(.search-bar) - height(.dates-bar) - height(.toolbar)"`

What can I do ? I don't want to use JavaScript for that. If it is possible with flexbox, I will use it.

EDIT: Here is the fiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/c38p8e70/

Comment: set up a jsfiddle so we can see exactly what you mean

Comment: Added a fiddle of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```css
body {margin:0;}
div {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.scroll-view {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">

</div>

<div class="dates-bar">

</div>

<div class="search-bar">

</div>

<div class="scroll-view-wrapper">
  <div class="scroll-view">
    <table class="table-view">
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k6uLfamq/1/ I put the last row "Hello" and I can never reach it with scrolling because the height goes beyond the viewport. Check out the green borders. They go beyond the viewport. I need to make it so that the bottom of the green borders is at the bottom of the **viewport**, not at the bottom of the container (`body` or `div.container`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using flexbox. Here is the CSS

```
 .container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
 }

 .scroll-view {
     flex-grow: 1;
 }
```